# How do you link to a Dexterity page from an ATContent page using "Related Items"?

Tags: plone, archetypes, dexterity

Tying to add a related item to an ATContent Page which links to a Dexterity page. However, in the popup-overlay (when selecting "Add..." from the "Categorization" tab) there is no checkbox option to add myDexterity type of content.

Am I missing something? is this supported? has anyone got a workaround?

Plone 4.1.2 (4111)
CMF 2.2.4
Zope 2.13.10
plone.app.dexterity 1.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a separate package for this behaviour:

[plone.app.referenceablebehavior](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.referenceablebehavior)

Just add it to your buildout (`eggs` and `zcml` variables, no need to install it via control panel). Then go to your dexterity control panel, in the Behaviours tab, and add the "Referenceable" behaviour. Note that only new contents will honor that behaviour, those that have been already created won't be refereceable.

Comment: it would be better to add the dependency in setup.py of your package; also check in your buildout to see if you're using the right KGS for this version of Dexterity: http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.0.3-1?plone=4.1.2

Comment: Provided that he does have a custom package (he didn't mentioned it).